# htaccess redirect subfolder to index with variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect users with htaccess. I want to redirect any wildcard subfolder to the index with subfolder as a php variable.

Example:

```
http://domain.com/abc
```

Change to:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?x=abc
```

I'm *pretty sure* I can do this is htaccess although I'm not 100%. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be easy, use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?x=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: absolutely perfect. thanks so much for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^abc /kat.php?index.php?x=abc [L]

############ or dynamic

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+) /kat.php?index.php?x=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I was trying exactly this but it wasn't working for me. thanks for the answer though!